# Jaws help solve problems instead of just editing

Tags: discussion

Jawa you can edit, can you help solve my problem please?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Exchange and Ask Different.

We are community edited and community supported, so some people will edit questions that need help or that they think need help.

Your best bet is to edit your question after reading the [about] and [help] sections for the main site. Providing details on what specifically you tried, researching an Apple support article or a post on the internet and explaining precisely what you are struggling with while following those instructions is the best way to attract a good answer to your post.